# Export OneNote content to mht format using api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am syncing OneNote notebooks into my application using MS graph API.Using Graph API I can get onenote pages in HTML format. I want the output to be in .mht/.pdf format. Does Onenote or MS Graph provide any api to get content in other format apart from HTML.

This is something similar to export onenote notebook in .mht or .pdf format.

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not support getting OneNote page content in .mht or .pdf formats.

You will need to use some conversion code to convert the retrieved HTML to the format you want.

But the page content HTML that we currently return, should primarily be used for reading the page content itself and not for rendering. If you were to use it to render, it will not look like the original OneNote page.

Here's a reference to the page content HTML that we currently return: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn832628.aspx